# Using LINQ to perform LEFT JOIN between datatable and submitted array

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, datatable

I have a large table in SQL server ('ManyColSQLTable' sample shown below) from which I want to perform a LEFT JOIN on a sample of dates and times (the 'myDateTimes' sample has both a Date and a Time column, and may include dates and times that are not in ManyColSQLTable).  The below SQL code does this correctly, for the case where myDateTimes exists as a seperate table in SQL server, but I would like to do this dynamically, with a submitted array of myDateTimes, using vb.net and LINQ.

1)  Use SQLDataAdapter to pull ManyColSQLTable into a vb.net DataTable, and then use LINQ to write a LEFT JOIN with the submitted myDateTimes. How to use LINQ syntax to then perform a LEFT JOIN with myDateTimes?  Note that myDateTimes are inputed as a vb.net array.

2) Alternatively, would it be more efficient to create a temp table in the database comprising the MyDateTimes array data (how to do?), and then perform the join using below TSQL syntax, before pulling the results back into vb.net (eg as DataTable using SQLDataAdapter).

Sample from ManyColSQLTable in SQL Server:

```
        Date        Time        EURUSD  USDJPY  GBPUSD  USDCAD
    1   2009-12-02  21:30:00    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
    2   2009-12-02  22:00:00    1.5047  87.4300 1.6636  1.0511
    3   2009-12-02  22:30:00    1.5048  87.6100 1.6640  1.0512
    4   2009-12-02  23:00:00    1.5061  87.5500 1.6652  1.0496
    5   2009-12-02  23:30:00    1.5067  87.6400 1.6661  1.0493
    ... ...         00:00:00    ...     ...     ...     ...
    108 2009-12-20  04:30:00    1.5088  86.7100 1.6756  1.0393
```

The following works in SQL Management Studio:

```
SELECT  distinct *
 FROM [dbo].myDateTimes as j
 LEFT JOIN ManyColSQLTable ON 
 (ManyColSQLTable.Date = j.date and ManyColSQLTable.time = j.time) 
 Order by j.date desc , j.time desc
```

My attempt using LINQ (syntax is clearly wrong - how to fix?):

```
Sub JoinExample()
        Dim myDateTimes() As Date = {#6/19/2013 12:30:00 AM#, #12/3/2009 3:00:00 AM#}
        Dim tbl As DataTable = FillDataTable()

        '  I'm stuck from this point on.  How get the syntax correct?
        Dim rsltTbl = From dt In myDateTimes
        Join [Date] In tbl.AsEnumerable() On
        dt Equals tbl.Columns([Date]) And dt.TimeOfDay Equals tbl.Columns([Time])
        Select tbl.Rows()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

Try this example:

```
Module StartupModule

    Sub Main()
        ' Mock data table.
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("Id", GetType(Integer))
        dt.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(DateTime))
        dt.Columns.Add("Description", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("Amount", GetType(Decimal))


        Dim addRow As Action(Of Integer, DateTime, String, Decimal?) = Sub(id, [date], description, amount)
                                                                           Dim r = dt.NewRow
                                                                           r.SetField("Id", id)
                                                                           r.SetField("Date", [date])

                                                                           If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(description)) Then
                                                                               r.SetField("Description", description)
                                                                           End If

                                                                           If (amount.HasValue) Then
                                                                               r.SetField("Amount", amount.Value)
                                                                           End If

                                                                           dt.Rows.Add(r)
                                                                       End Sub

        ' Populate the table.
        addRow(1, #1/1/2016 11:11:11 AM#, "First row", 100D)
        addRow(2, #1/1/2017 10:10:10 AM#, "Second row", 200D)
        addRow(3, #1/1/2018 9:09:09 AM#, Nothing, 300.05D)
        addRow(4, #1/1/2019 8:08:08 AM#, "Fourth row", Nothing)

        ' Some dates in an array.
        Dim dates As DateTime() = {
            #1/1/2016 11:11:11 AM#,
            #1/1/2017 10:10:11 AM#,
            #1/1/2018 9:09:09 AM#,
            #1/1/2019 8:08:08 AM#
        }

        ' Dates array left join data table.
        Dim rows = From arrayRow In dates
                   Group Join tableRow In dt
                   On tableRow.Field(Of DateTime)("date") Equals arrayRow Into tableRows = Group
                   From tableRow In tableRows.DefaultIfEmpty(dt.NewRow)
                   Select
                        arrayRow,
                        Id = If(tableRow.Field(Of Integer?)("Id").GetValueOrDefault = 0, "", tableRow.Field(Of Integer)("Id").ToString),
                        [Date] = If(tableRow.Field(Of DateTime?)("Date").GetValueOrDefault = DateTime.MinValue, "", tableRow.Field(Of DateTime)("Date").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")),
                        Description = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(tableRow.Field(Of String)("Description")), "", tableRow.Field(Of String)("Description")),
                        Amount = If(tableRow.Field(Of Decimal?)("Amount") Is Nothing, "", tableRow.Field(Of Decimal)("Amount").ToString("C"))

        ' Display results.
        For Each row In rows
            Console.WriteLine("LDate:{0}  Id:{1}  RDate:{2}  Descr:{3}  Amount:{4}", row.arrayRow, row.Id, row.Date, row.Description, row.Amount)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

First of all, I have to say that this implementation (separating a `DateTime` into two columns date and time) seems odd, makes things more difficult and error prone. Breaking a `DateTime` domain (which actually describes a moment in time) into two, that of Date and Time, changes entirely the meaning of the first. I strongly suggest (if you can to perform this change) to make it one column.

That said, I believe the best way is to combine in your select statement the Date and Time columns into one column, so in your data table would have a column of `DateTime` so you can easily perform an equality check.

I have edited the example to suit as more to your needs.

Now, about you main problem, you might want to look at [How to: Combine Data with LINQ by Using Joins (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918093.aspx#Y916)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks promising but how to return the data in other columns in ManyColSQLTable.  I've been trying to do so, but get lost with the 'Group' clauses.  I should add that the [Date] and [Time] columns are joiint primary keys in the ManyColSQLTable.  Given this, are the Group clauses still needed?

Answer (score 0):

you can do left outer join between table like this

```
var rowDataLeftOuter = from rowLeft in lefttbl.AsEnumerable()
                       join rowRight in rightble.AsEnumerable() 
      on rowLeft[colToJoinOn] equals rowRight[strTempColName] into gj
                       from subRight in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select lefttbl.ItemArray.Concat((subRight== null) ?
            (rightble.NewRow().ItemArray) :subRight.ItemArray).ToArray();
```

Code is in C# but you can use converter to convert to vb.net